# What is difference between SQL Report viewer webpart and showing the report via page viewer webpart?

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, tfs, page-viewer-web-part, report-viewer

We have not yet configured Reporting integration on our SharePoint site. Currently the way we show TFS reports are by adding the page viewer webpart to the SharePoint dashboard and then pointing this webpart to the URL of the respective report.

I would like to know what benefits/features will I get if:

1. If I configure the SharePoint reporting integration?
2. If I use the SQL Report viewer webpart?

From what I have read so far, the only advantage of performing point 1 (configure the SharePoint reporting integration) is that we can then use point 2 (SQL Report viewer webpart). Besides this what are the benefits.. Our only purpose is to show TFS reports on the SharePoint dashboard. Do you think we need to configure the reporting services and use the report viewer webpart? Or the page viewer webpart is sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SharePoint integration, you can host Reports and other SSRS files in SharePoint document library, including but not limited to defining permissions for individual reports using SharePoint permission model (users, groups, permission levels).

When using Report Viewer web part, you can configure lots of details regarding the displayed report using the web part properties, such as what items are shown on the toolbar, preset parameters for report, etc. You can also connect SharePoint filter web parts to SSRS Web Part to define report parameters on the fly from QueryString, user profile properties, etc.

TFS reports don't sound like they would benefit from SP integration features, but you need to consider your requirements with the features mentioned above. To me it sounds you wouldn't be needing the features SP integration brings.

Comment: Yes. Right that's what I was wondering. Thanks for your inputs